# Limit editing to specific fields in a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am wanting to allow limited editing of a SharePoint 2010 list item, to allow only editing of a few fields, depending on data in another sharepoint list. I have two lists:

```
Stock
=====
Stock Item   Maximum Stock Level   Current Stock Level
----------   -------------------   -------------------
My Item      100                   10
My Item 2    200                   25

Permissions
===========
Stock Item (lookup)    Users (person, multiple)
-------------------    ------------------------
My Item                User 1
My Item 2              User 2
```

When 'User 1' clicks on My Item, 'Edit Item' is disabled (since they are in a custom group 'Stock Updaters'). I then want another icon in the ribbon 'Update Stock', which they click on and a form shows that allows them to edit the current stock level only. When they view 'My Item 2', either 'Update Stock' is disabled, or it just shows a view stating they don't have access to update the data.

How can I implement this, using InfoPath 2010? If they need to have contribute rights to update the data, is there a way of preventing this (unless they are an admin), or the prevent the edit form being shown (perhaps through workflows, showing a different form instead)?

Comment: I am not sure why do you need Infopath 2007 for this. You have a list and you have the Edit form (Editform.aspx) which you need to customize with some logic.

Comment: It's that logic I need to figure out... also using InfoPath 2010 since it will be easier for others (without web design experience) to update the form and there isn't a dependency on SharePoint Designer or a custom feature.

Answer (score 1):

Have you explored custom list forms? That will give you control to execute custom rules and enable/disable fields based on whatever rules you have.